# Notify the Service if the Activity is Down

Tags: android, android-service

Sometimes my app crashes for some reason and I have no control over it.
I want to let the service know when the app crashes and do some other process.

Is it possible to do that?
By the way, starting from Lollipop, `getRunningTasks` is deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of Service you have?

Comment: use android service [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172092/check-if-activity-is-running-from-service]

Comment: when app crashes, that I  assume means your app is killed, in that case Android system will kill all it's components like Activity, and Service. So it means Service itself is killed. This don't leave any scope to `notify` anything to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to catch exception in application and then start your service. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829955/android-handle-application-crash-and-start-a-particular-activity/34851628)

Comment: for a big App, you can not add try and catch in every activity

Comment: Check carefully. You do not add it in activity. You add it in application class.

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes my app crashes for some reason and I have no control over
>   it.

You need to debug the exact reason for crash, but in General, if you have a `Service` running, then Android will notice that you have a service running and not kill it so readily. However, it is still possible that Android will kill your service process if it isn't "in use".

> I want to let the service know when the app crashes and do some other
>   process.

Assuming App crashes here means your app's process is killed by Android system, and in such an event, `Service` will stop running when system kill your application. Basically When your application is killed by the system, all components of it are killed (activities, services, etc.).

Hence, this situation don't leave any scope to notify anything to your app's service as it is already gone with app crash.